# button that take the date of datepicker(year,month,day) in android studio

Tags: java, android

i want to take the date that looks like that ("Year-mm-DD") from date picker in android studio and compare if it with the current date when i press a button.

```
public class UserMenu extends ActionBarActivity {
    DatePicker date;
    ImageButton next;
    Date currentDate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_menu);
        date = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nxt);
        currentDate = new Date();
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String dateFormat = dateformat.format(new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDayOfMonth()));
                String nowDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(currentDate);
                if (dateFormat.compareTo(nowDate) < 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The date is too old", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(UserMenu.this, UserMenuTime.class);
                    i.putExtra("date", dateFormat);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please post what you've tried so far

Comment: please give tell us what is the issue with above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [before](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) and [after](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) methods to compare dates:

```
   Date pickerDate = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDayOfMonth());
   if (pickerDate.before(currentDate)) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The date is too old", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   } else {
       Intent i = new Intent(UserMenu.this, UserMenuTime.class);
       i.putExtra("date", dateFormat);
       startActivity(i);
   }
```